# Looking for a Remote Desktop Android Application with Left-Click and Right-Click Buttons on Android App

Tags: android, remote-desktop

I've tried using programs like TeamViewer, but touch-based mouse clicks didn't work well within some windows programs. While free would be great, I'm also open to inexpensive paid options as long as they're not subscription-based. The program must allow access from an Android mobile app to a Windows PC and should have buttons on the app corresponding to left-click and right-click of the mouse.

I have been using an app called CrazyRemote Pro, which meets the above conditions. However, I'm feeling uneasy about continuing to use it because it seems like the developer has gone out of business. Their website has been shut down and the app has been removed from the Play Store.